# Where did the Self language get its name?

Tags: programming-languages, smalltalk, selflanguage

Why was the language given such a hard to google name?

Comment: Easy: because Google did not exist when it was invented ;-)

Comment: You think "Self" is hard-to-Google?  How about "C"?!?  (Although to be fair, 3 of the first 10 Google hits for "C" are about the language, while only two of the top 10 Google hits for "Self" are about the language.  YMMV :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aSe8dJUKjqSYJ%3aforums.on3network.co.nz/index.php%3Ftopic%3D77242.0+self+language+%22called+self+because%22&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.co.uk):

> It is called 'SELF' because Dr David
>   Ungar got called to many many nerd
>   lecturers and got sick of writing his
>   name on his name badge and just wrote
>   'Self' instead. SELF is a good name
>   for it as it automatically assumes
>   default self method calls for
>   automatic inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, Dogbane is right. And it really is a hard to google name so i use "self language" in quotes.

Dave Ungar told the story himself in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ka4KY7TMTU
Very interesting: he talks about the design principles behind Self.